# Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Producer transactionality in a reactive Spring Webflux application

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, project-reactor, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I am working with Spring Cloud Stream Binder Kafka 3.0.0 in a Spring Webflux applications that exposes an API that receives some data and publishes it to a Kafka topic using an `@Output`:

```
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var producer: Producer

    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(CREATED)
    fun create(@RequestBody metrics: SomeMetric): Mono<Void> {
        producer.send(metrics)
        return Mono.empty()
    }
```

```
@Component
class Producer(private val producerSources: ProducerSources) {

    @Transactional
    fun send(metrics: SomeMetric) {
        producerSources.metrics().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(metrics)                       .build())
    }            
}
```

```
interface ProducerSources {

    @Output("metrics")
    fun metrics(): MessageChannel

    //Other...

}
```

I have configured both Kafka and the Spring Boot app to use transactional producers (notice the the `@Transactional` annotation on the send method above):

```
@Configuration
class KafkaProducerConfiguration {

    @Bean
    fun transactionManager(binders: BinderFactory): PlatformTransactionManager {
        val pf = (binders.getBinder("kafka",
                MessageChannel::class.java) as KafkaMessageChannelBinder).transactionalProducerFactory
        return KafkaTransactionManager<ByteArray, ByteArray>(pf)
    }
```

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableBinding(value = [ProducerSources::class])
@SpringBootApplication
class MyApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<MyApplication>(*args)
}
```

The point is, being a Spring Webflux application I shouldn't be blocking the http thread so I should wrap the (blocking) producer on a fromCallable block and execute it on another thread pool, something like:

```
@Component
class Producer(private val producerSources: ProducerSources) {

    @Transactional
    fun send(metrics: SomeMetric) : Mono<Unit> {
        Mono.fromCallable {
            producerSources.metrics().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(metrics)                       .build())           
       }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic())
    }

}
```

```
    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(CREATED)
    fun create(@RequestBody metrics: SomeMetric): Mono<Void> {
        return producer.send(metrics)
    }
```

My questions are:

- Does the `@Transactional` annotation still work with this approach? I guess it shouldn't...
- What's the recommended way to support transactionality in a reactive Spring Webflux + Cloud Stream Kafka context?
- BONUS: Is [Reactor Kafka](https://projectreactor.io/docs/kafka/release/reference/#transactional-sender) supported in Spring Cloud Stream? In case it is, how could we configure it in this case `@Output`, transactional support...?

Comment: Have you looked at this post - https://spring.io/blog/2019/05/16/reactive-transactions-with-spring. There are samples and details. Perhaps we need to retrofit it in our docs somehow.

Comment: Hi Oleg, yes I had already read that post. The point is it is focused on database transactions, but KafkaTransactionManager is not a reactive transaction manager so it shouldn't work. Reactor Kafka seems to support transactional sends `KafkaSender.create(senderOptions).sendTransactionally` but I'm not sure how that fits in Spring Cloud Stream...

Comment: I've also had a look a this sample: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/blob/master/source-samples/dynamic-destination-source-kafka/src/main/java/demo/DynamicDestinationSourceApplication.java But it's kind of halfway, on the one hand it uses a reactive source but on the other, it's still a webmvc application.